# Python argparse: Force a list item to be unique

Tags: python, argparse

Being able to validate the list items using `choices=servers` below is nice.

```
servers = [ "ApaServer", "BananServer", "GulServer", "SolServer", "RymdServer", "SkeppServer", "HavsServer", "SovServer" ]
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--only', nargs='*', choices=servers, help='Space separated list of case sensitive server names to process')
```

Is it possible to force an item in the list to be unique, so that no duplicates are allowed?

Comment: Just cast the list of servers to a `set` and that will strip duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to properly discard duplicates using `argparse` would be to create your own `argparse.Action` class that takes care of using `set` as suggestted by other answers:

```
import argparse

class UniqueAppendAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        unique_values = set(values)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, unique_values)

servers = ["ApaServer", "BananServer", "GulServer", "SolServer",
           "RymdServer", "SkeppServer", "HavsServer", "SovServer" ]
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--only', nargs='*', choices=servers, action=UniqueAppendAction,
                    help='Space separated list of case sensitive server names to process')
print parser.parse_args()
```

Example output:

```
$ python test.py -o ApaServer ApaServer
Namespace(only=set(['ApaServer']))
```

Comment: I don't see any value over a simple `args.only = set(args.only)` after `args = parser.parse_args()`.  Much shorter than writing a custom action...

Comment: @lunaryorn For a single argument, I agree on that this isn't going to be really convenient. However, when multiple arguments should have this property, setting it in the `add_argument` method call is more consistent and readable since all the information about the argument is a single place.

Comment: In this case you can still do `for arg in ('only1', 'only2'):  setattr(args, arg, set(getattr(args, arg)))`.  But I see your point...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think, that you can enforce this with `argparse`, but I also don't see any reason to do so.  Just document in `help` that duplicates are ignored.  If the user passes duplicate arguments to `--only`, just let her do so, and ignore the duplicate argument when processing the option arguments (e.g. by turing the list into a `set()` before processing).

Comment: Consider also issuing a warning to `stderr` that duplicate arguments will be ignored, if discovered.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying Michel's answer:

```
In [1]: x = [5,6,5]

In [2]: x_nodups = list(set(x))

In [3]: x_nodups
Out[3]: [5, 6]

In [4]: x_nodups_michel = dict(map(lambda i: (i,1),x)).keys()

In [5]: x_nodups_michel
Out[5]: [5, 6]
```

Much shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excerpt from some code that I use for a similar purpose:

```
def parse_args(argv):
    class SetAction(argparse.Action):
        """argparse.Action subclass to store distinct values"""
        def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
            try:
                getattr(namespace,self.dest).update( values )
            except AttributeError:
                setattr(namespace,self.dest,set(values))
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description = __doc__,
        formatter_class = argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
        )
    ap.add_argument('--genes', '-g',
                    type = lambda v: v.split(','),
                    action = SetAction,
                    help = 'select by specified gene')
```

This is similar in spirit to jcollado's reply, with a modest improvement: multiple options can be specified, with comma separated values, and they are deduped (via set) across all options.

For example:

```
snafu$ ./bin/ucsc-bed -g BRCA1,BRCA2,DMD,TNFA,BRCA2 -g BRCA1
Namespace(genes=set([u'BRCA1', u'BRCA2', u'DMD', u'TNFA']))
```

Note that there are two -g args. BRCA2 is specified twice in the first, but appears only once. BRCA1 is specified in the first and second -g opts, but also appears only once.