# Convert one list to set, but if empty use a default one

Tags: python, list, set

I'm looking for a nicer way to assign a set with the conent of a list if such list is not empty, otherwise another list should be used.

If it is possible I'd like a nicer way to write this (or an argument to why this is the nicest way):

```
if args.onlyTheseServers:
    only = set(args.onlyTheseServers)
else:
    only = set(availableServers)
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that the official Python style guide ([PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) doesn't like you calling your variable or attributes `onlyTheseServers`; it would prefer `only_these_servers` or such.

Comment: `is not None` will be True if you pass an empty list, do you actually want the condition to be empty list or the variable to be None?

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Thanks! I´ll look through it and adopt. I´m a bit Java-fied. :-)

Comment: @Geekfish: I wrote `if args.onlyTheseServers is not None:` but yes, I do want the condition to be false if onlyTheseServers is an empty list. Thanks for spotting it! I am changing it to `if args.onlyTheseServers:`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
only = set(args.onlyTheseServers or availableServers)
```

Comment: That has slightly different semantics than the original. It may or may not matter, but if `args.onlyTheseServers` is an empty list then the original produces an empty set whereas your version would use the default.

Comment: True indeed. The semantics are different from his sample code, but actually match the question title ("... with the contents of a list if the list isn't empty...").

Comment: I had a bug in my code sample. So you interpreted it as I wanted it, despite my example being buggy. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9376670/183066), I'd say that what you're really looking for is a way to assign a default value to a missing parameter using `argparse`. In that case you should just use `default` as follows:

```
parser.add_argument('-o', '--only', default=default_servers, ...)
```

This way, when the `-o/--only` option isn't passed, the namespace will have the default value correctly set.

Comment: Well noticed. I think that that is indeed what he wants. I'm now annoyed that I didn't think of it myself... without having connected it with the previous question I *had* connected it with argparse due to the variable name `args`!

Comment: @Chris Morgan: Well, I am a confusing questioner. Sorry about that!

Comment: Nice deduction! I´ve solved it the way you suggested. However, to let my question here "stand on its own" (and to possibly help someone else with it) I´m marking the other one as my preferred answer. Although it feels a bit bad, if only I had more up-votes to give. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`args.onlyTheseServers` seems a variable coming from `argparse`.

If that's your case you should check the [`default`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/argparse.html#default) argument and the [`set_default()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/argparse.html#parser-defaults) method.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='*', default=['1', '2', '3'])
>>> args = parser.parse_args()
>>> args.foo
['1', '2', '3']
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a', 'b'])
>>> args.foo
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Nice deduction! I´ve solved it the way you suggested. However, to let my question here "stand on its own" (and to possibly help someone else with it) I´m marking the other one as my preferred answer. Although it feels a bit bad, if only I had more up-votes to give. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not really much better, but at least a bit shorter:

```
only = set(availableServers if args.onlyTheseServers is None 
           else args.onlyTheseServers)
```

You can also do

```
only = set(args.onlyTheseServers or availableServers)
```

It works slightly different as it does not test for `None`, but only if the argument is true-is - in this case it should work though.

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy buy I like this better

```
only = set(args.onlyTheseServers) if args.onlyTheseServers is not None else set(availableServers)
```

Comment: I´ll actually have to call you crazy on that one. ;-) But thanks for answering! Have a zero-vote (voting down a correct answer would be cruel). :-)

Comment: @Kent, hehe. It's cause I completely buy the 'one case is the common one and should be first' explanation given in the documentation of pep 308. http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html

So you read it only = set(args.onlyTheseServers) ... bla bla some special case treated here...